# Cannot manage APM Level on WDC WD100EMAZ

Tags: hard-drive, proxmox, hdparm

I was looking into configuring some sleep schedules for my server disks, but it looks like I cannot change any settings on my drives. I am looking for some help on this because I am pretty inexperienced with configuring `hdparm` settings.

## Error Message

```bash
sudo hdparm -B 127 /dev/sda

/dev/sda:
 setting Advanced Power Management level to 0x7f (127)
SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  70 00 05 00 00 00 00 0a 00 00 00 00 24 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
 APM_level      = 164
```

## Drive Info

```bash
sudo hdparm -I /dev/sda

/dev/sda:

ATA device, with non-removable media
        Model Number:       WDC WD100EMAZ-00WJTA0                   
        Serial Number:      'REDACTED'
        Firmware Revision:  83.H0A83
        Transport:          Serial, ATA8-AST, SATA 1.0a, SATA II Extensions, SATA Rev 2.5, SATA Rev 2.6, SATA Rev 3.0; Revision: ATA8-AST T13 Project D1697 Revision 0b
Standards:
        Used: unknown (minor revision code 0x0029) 
        Supported: 9 8 7 6 5 
        Likely used: 9
Configuration:
        Logical         max     current
        cylinders       16383   16383
        heads           16      16
        sectors/track   63      63
        --
        CHS current addressable sectors:    16514064
        LBA    user addressable sectors:   268435455
        LBA48  user addressable sectors: 19532873728
        Logical  Sector size:                   512 bytes
        Physical Sector size:                  4096 bytes
        Logical Sector-0 offset:                  0 bytes
        device size with M = 1024*1024:     9537536 MBytes
        device size with M = 1000*1000:    10000831 MBytes (10000 GB)
        cache/buffer size  = unknown
        Form Factor: 3.5 inch
        Nominal Media Rotation Rate: 5400
Capabilities:
        LBA, IORDY(can be disabled)
        Queue depth: 32
        Standby timer values: specd by Standard, no device specific minimum
        R/W multiple sector transfer: Max = 16  Current = 0
        Advanced power management level: 164
        DMA: mdma0 mdma1 mdma2 udma0 udma1 udma2 udma3 udma4 udma5 *udma6 
             Cycle time: min=120ns recommended=120ns
        PIO: pio0 pio1 pio2 pio3 pio4 
             Cycle time: no flow control=120ns  IORDY flow control=120ns
Commands/features:
        Enabled Supported:
           *    SMART feature set
                Security Mode feature set
           *    Power Management feature set
           *    Write cache
           *    Look-ahead
           *    Host Protected Area feature set
           *    WRITE_BUFFER command
           *    READ_BUFFER command
           *    NOP cmd
           *    DOWNLOAD_MICROCODE
           *    Advanced Power Management feature set
                Power-Up In Standby feature set
           *    SET_FEATURES required to spinup after power up
                SET_MAX security extension
           *    48-bit Address feature set
           *    Device Configuration Overlay feature set
           *    Mandatory FLUSH_CACHE
           *    FLUSH_CACHE_EXT
           *    SMART error logging
           *    SMART self-test
           *    Media Card Pass-Through
           *    General Purpose Logging feature set
           *    WRITE_{DMA|MULTIPLE}_FUA_EXT
           *    64-bit World wide name
           *    URG for READ_STREAM[_DMA]_EXT
           *    URG for WRITE_STREAM[_DMA]_EXT
           *    WRITE_UNCORRECTABLE_EXT command
           *    {READ,WRITE}_DMA_EXT_GPL commands
           *    Segmented DOWNLOAD_MICROCODE
                unknown 119[6]
                unknown 119[7]
           *    Gen1 signaling speed (1.5Gb/s)
           *    Gen2 signaling speed (3.0Gb/s)
           *    Gen3 signaling speed (6.0Gb/s)
           *    Native Command Queueing (NCQ)
           *    Host-initiated interface power management
           *    Phy event counters
           *    NCQ priority information
           *    READ_LOG_DMA_EXT equivalent to READ_LOG_EXT
                Non-Zero buffer offsets in DMA Setup FIS
           *    DMA Setup Auto-Activate optimization
                Device-initiated interface power management
                In-order data delivery
           *    Software settings preservation
                unknown 78[7]
                unknown 78[10]
                unknown 78[11]
           *    SMART Command Transport (SCT) feature set
           *    SCT Write Same (AC2)
           *    SCT Error Recovery Control (AC3)
           *    SCT Features Control (AC4)
           *    SCT Data Tables (AC5)
           *    SANITIZE feature set
           *    OVERWRITE_EXT command
           *    Extended number of user addressable sectors 
           *    WRITE BUFFER DMA command
           *    READ BUFFER DMA command
Security: 
        Master password revision code = 65534
                supported
        not     enabled
        not     locked
        not     frozen
        not     expired: security count
        not     supported: enhanced erase
        1006min for SECURITY ERASE UNIT.
Logical Unit WWN Device Identifier: 5000cca273dc4eaf
        NAA             : 5
        IEEE OUI        : 000cca
        Unique ID       : 273dc4eaf
Checksum: correct
```

## Hardware & OS:

- Proxmox 7.4-17
- Drives connected to DELL HBA330 J7TNV 12Gb/s 3rd Gen LSI SAS3008 HBA 9300 9311-8i
- WDC WD100EMAZ-00WJTA0 Drive model
- Disks are part of a Raid Z2 array Configured with the Proxmox host.

## Goal

I would like to successfully configure these drives to sleep after 10 minutes of inactivity with:

```bash
 hdparm -S 120 /dev/sda \
hdparm -S 120 /dev/sdb \
hdparm -S 120 /dev/sdc \
hdparm -S 120 /dev/sdf \
hdparm -S 120 /dev/sdg \
hdparm -S 120 /dev/sdh
```

With the understanding that APM must be less than 128 to all for spindown configuration.

Comment: What is the goal with sleeping drives? Generally, drive longevity is best when the drives remain running for the duration.

Comment: The drives are on my home server and are infrequently accessed. I've been running them with no spin down for a few years with that logic, but now I'm looking to cut power usage. I figure the 10 minute to spin down delay will help reduce power but not make them unusable when actually accessing. Summary: save about 40watts average.

Comment: It might be worth your while to replace the hard drives with SSDs. That will give you the power saving you want

Comment: Unfortunately getting 40tb of usable SSD is a bit pricey still. I hope to do so in the future when they are at price parity.

Comment: Do your drive spin up again (almost) right away after `hdparm -y /dev/sdX`? (Or, does the command spin down your drive at all?) And does it make a difference if the drive is not mounted at all?

Comment: I forgot to mention that the error:
```
SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:
```
Is also presented when I run the hdparm -S commands. It appears as if nothing is happening and I cannot write settings at all. I will try the `-y` flag soon.

Comment: I'm suspecting it has something to do with your HBA. Not sure if it just doesn't get along with hdparm well, or if it's actually forbidding some commands intentionally. I don't know much about SAS HBAs, but if it deals with SCSI-ATA translation by itself (i.e., work like USB/UAS bridge instead of exposing itself as an AHCI controller), maybe it filters SCSI ATA PASSTHROUGH commands with certain content (ATA commands). If that's the case, maybe it allows you to fiddle the timer with the non-passthrough way (scsi mode pages). See if you can get sg3_utils and share `sg_vpd -p ai /dev/sda`.

Comment: Apparently error in text is "illegal request: invalid field in CDB". CDB stands for command descriptor block. Basically it's fancy way to call the main body / instruction part of the SCSI command. In SCSI ATA PASSTHROUGH command, ATA command like IDLE is one of its field. I can't tell for sure but I think it is at least a way the HBA can put it for telling you that the it does not allow/expect user to ATA PASSTHROUGH the command you are sending (IDLE).

Comment: In addition to / instead of `sg_vpd`, you may want to get sdparm and run `sdparm -a /dev/sdX`. See if there's any mode page that contains a field called `Standby_z`. If so, please add that whole mode page to your question.

Comment: Btw, can you also check if `hdparm -C /dev/sdX` give you similar error?

Answer (score 0):

According the ACS-3 [(PDF)](https://people.freebsd.org/%7Eimp/asiabsdcon2015/works/d2161r5-ATAATAPI_Command_Set_-_3.pdf):

```
4.6 Advanced Power Management (APM) feature set

...

The APM feature set is independent of the Standby timer (see 4.15.3).
If the APM feature set is enabled and the Standby timer is enabled,
then the device shall go to the PM:2 Standby state if:

a) the Standby timer expires; or
b) a vendor specific APM algorithm indicates that the PM:2 Standby
   state should be entered.
```

> With the understanding that APM must be less than 128 to all for spindown configuration.

Therefore, AFAICT, this is really just referring to `b)`, that is, with APM level >= 128, an `APM algorithm` that will never `indicate that the PM:2 Standby state should be entered` will be used. It does NOT mean that the APM level / algorithm will invalidate the Standby timer.

According to `4.15.3 Standby timer`, the only cause that prevents the Standby timer from "working" is `a media access command is received`. I assume `media access command` refers to command that triggers a read / write operation. `If a media access command is received and the Standby timer is enabled, the Standby timer is reinitialized to the value specified by the most recent IDLE command ... and started.` (According to the man page of `hdparm`, the command sent with `-S 120` should be an IDLE command.)

Comment: Thank you for the dive into the docs. I forgot to mention that the provided the same error when trying the `hdparm -S 120 /dev/sda` command as shown below:


```bash
root@myserver:~# hdparm -S 120 /dev/sda

/dev/sda:
 setting standby to 120 (10 minutes)
SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  70 00 05 00 00 00 00 0a 00 00 00 00 24 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

Answer (score 0):

The command `hdparm -S 120 /dev/sda` should make the drives sleep after 10 minutes of inactivity. However, whether or not this works depends on the firmware of the specific HDD. If you've tried setting the APM level and `hdparm -S` with no luck, then perhaps the specific drive you have does not support these settings.

I have drives that do not respond to `hdparm`. For some of these I've had luck with instead using [openSeaChest](https://github.com/Seagate/openSeaChest). This tool can configure power settings using Extended Power Condition (EPC) which is not supported by `hdparm`.

With openSeaChest you can check the current EPC power settings of an HDD using:

```
openSeaChest_PowerControl -d /dev/sdb --showEPCSettings
```

The output of this command will also make it clear if the HDD supports EPC
or not. If it does, then the following command can be used to change the power setting with EPC:

```
openSeaChest_PowerControl -d /dev/sdX --idle_c MILLISECONS --standby_z MILLISECONS
```

This sets the idle C and standby C times of the disk `sdX` to `MILLISECONDS` of milliseconds:

If using EPC does not work either then `hd-idle` can be used as a last resort. This program does not rely on the firmware on the disc spinning down automatically. Instead is monitors the disk in software and spins them down after a period of inactivity. This works even on disks that can't spin down themselves. The following command spinds down the disk `sdX` after `SECONDS` of seconds.

```
hd-idle -a /dev/sdX -i SECONDS
```

To spin down all of your disks after 10 minutes you can use the command:

```
hd-idle -i 0
  -a /dev/sda -i 600 -a /dev/sdb -i 600
  -a /dev/sdc -i 600 -a /dev/sdf -i 600
  -a /dev/sdh -i 600 -a /dev/sdg -i 600
```

The `hd-idle` package also comes with a systemd service that can be enabled to turn on spindown at boot.